# r check if package version is greater than x.y.z

Tags: r, package, version

R packages have version numbers like 1.97.1. I can check what the version number is with

```
 packageVersion("data.table")
```

On my computer this returns 1.10.0.

What I want to do is check whether the data.table version is newer than say 1.9.7 because versions after 1.9.7 have a feature that my code needs. I've tried splitting the version into its constituent parts and evaluating them in different ways but I haven't figured out any robust way of doing this. 
Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: the `utils` package has a `compareVersion` function.

Comment: Or even just `if(packageVersion("data.table") > "1.9.7") { print("OK!\n") }`

Comment: @Benjamin - you should make that an answer. I've never heard of that function before - looks useful.

Comment: @G5W - `"1.10.0" > "1.9.8"` returns `FALSE`. `utils::compareVersion("1.10.0","1.9.8")` on the other hand returns `1` to indicate `1.10.0` is a later version

Comment: @thelatemail  I think that you are getting a string comparison.  for me  `packageVersion("data.table")` gives "1.10.0" and `packageVersion("data.table") > "1.9.8"` gives true

Comment: @G5W - my apologies - I didn't realise that `packageVersion` returns a different object with it's own class and comparison, and not just a simple text string. The things you learn

Comment: I don't fully understand what's going on but `str(packageVersion("data.table")` returns a packageVersion class which has a hidden int list with the three elements of the version number. So it looks like @GSW's first comment is the way to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While `utils::compareVersion()` is fine, I would say that using `packageVersion()` with comparison operators (as indicated by @G5W in comments) is simpler:

```
packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.10.0’
> packageVersion("data.table")>"1.9.8"
[1] TRUE
> packageVersion("data.table")>"1.10.01"
[1] FALSE
> packageVersion("data.table")=="1.10.0"
[1] TRUE
```

This is illustrated in the examples for `?packageVersion`; the ability to use comparison operators in this way is explicitly documented in `?package_version`:

> Functions `numeric_version`, `package_version` and
> `R_system_version` create a representation from such strings (if
> suitable) which allows for coercion and testing, combination,
> comparison, summaries (min/max), inclusion in data frames,
> subscripting, and printing.  The classes can hold a vector of such
> representations.

Comment: `compareVersion()` does not respect the [precedence rules of semantic versioning](http://semver.org/#spec-item-11). `"1.2.3.9000"` indicates a development version, and yet `compareVersion("1.2.3.9000", "1.2.3")` is `1`. Is there a pre-built alternative that follows the convention?

Answer (score 7):

As suggested by Benjamin, the right tool is `compareVersion`:

```
version_above <- function(pkg, than) {
  as.logical(compareVersion(as.character(packageVersion(pkg)), than))
}

packageVersion("ggplot2")
# [1] '2.2.1'
version_above("ggplot2", "2.0.0")
# [1] TRUE
version_above("ggplot2", "3.0.0")
# [1] FALSE
```

Outcomes of `compareVersion(a, b)` are

- `-1` if `a < b`
- `0` if `a == b`
- `1` if `a > b`

Source:

`?utils::compareVersion`

Answer (score 1):

Small guide how to work with packages versions.

"package_version" and/or "numeric_version" classes are used to represent a package version. (`class(packageVersion("base"))`).
We could use the `numeric_version`/`as.numeric_version` functions for conversion too.

What is difference between `numeric_version` and `package_version` functions (or classes connected with them). **There is almost no difference**.  Both are wrappers over the `.make_numeric_version` function and the latter one have one extra usage of working directly with `R.version`.

```r
v1 <- structure(list(c(1L, 10L, 1L)), class = "numeric_version")
# or numeric_version("1.10.1")
v2 <- `class<-`(list(c(1L, 9L, 8L)), class = "numeric_version")

v1 > v2
# This will still work as the numeric_version has a priority under the `>` operator 
# so the simple character is converted to numeric_version.
v1 > "1.9.8"
"1.10.1" > v2
# direct comparison for characters will fail
"1.10.1" > "1.9.8"

# comparing with utils::compareVersion
compareVersion("1.10.1", "1.9.8")
# comparing versions vector with pacs::compareVersionsMax or pacs::compareVersionsMin
pacs::compareVersionsMax(c("1.1.1", "1.0.0", "3.3.3"))
```