# Hyphen (`-`) in R package versions

Tags: r, package, version

A package I'm depending on lists versions like `4.0.4` but also `0.9-7` and even `0.9-7.1`. (cf. [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/bit64/)).

What does the hyphen (`-`) mean in package versioning? How is version comparison performed against it?   I couldn't find any docs on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What does the hyphen (`-`) mean in package versioning?*

The hyphen is mentioned in `?numeric_version`:

> "Numeric versions are sequences of one or more non-negative integers, usually (e.g., in package '`DESCRIPTION`' files) represented as character strings with the elements of the sequence concatenated and separated by single `.` or `-` characters. R package versions consist of at least two such integers."

Here, no distinction is made between the period `.` and the hyphen `-`. However, as noted by Hadley & Brian in [R Packages; Package metadata - Version](https://r-pkgs.org/description.html#version):

> I don’t recommend taking full advantage of R’s flexibility. Instead always use `.` to separate version numbers.

They refer to [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/), where the [use of hyphen is described](https://semver.org/#spec-item-9):

> A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a hyphen and a series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch version.

---

*How is version comparison performed against it?*

For version comparison, see [r check if package version is greater than x.y.z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495639/r-check-if-package-version-is-greater-than-x-y-z) and [R Packages; Package metadata - Version](https://r-pkgs.org/description.html#version).